# Debug view, left click on call stack

Tags: debugging, eclipse-plugin, callstack

I am developing plug-in project in eclipse. It is attached to debug context. In debug when i click on call stack in debug view i need to extract line in code (current executing instruction).
Other words, how to set up listener to listen left click on call stack and get?

Comment: Debugging what language? Java? C++? or any number of other things that Eclipse can debug

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, implemented `ISelectionChangedListener` and overwrite `public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event);` i works just like i expected, reacts on debug context change (mouse click or next line).